# Docker image works fine locally but fails in gitlab

Tags: docker, hive, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I baked a custom image for hive by making some changes in the Dockerfile here https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/master/packaging/src/docker (commented out line 70). The image created with it works fine on my local Docker container, but fails in gitlab. It is stuck at this state:
[image]

This is how part of my .gitlab-ci.yml look like:

```yml
    default:
      tags:
        - citools
        - gcp
    
    stages:
      - deploy
    
    deploy_hiveserver2:
      stage: deploy
      image:
        name: docker-sandbox.artifactory.<xyz>/apache-hive:0.2
    
    variables:
      SERVICE_NAME: hiveserver2
      SERVICE_OPTS: "-Dhive.metastore.uris=thrift://<abc>:9083"
      IS_RESUME: "true"
    
    
    before_script:
      - echo "before script"
      #- apt-get update
      #- git status
    
    script:
      - echo "Deploy job triggered for HiveServer2"
      - ls
      - whoami
      - pwd
```

If I use the official hive image from docker-hub, it does not fail at the step it is failing now. Is there any additional config I need to set in gitlab?

Comment: I'm not an expert in gitlab. However, did I get it right that `Executing step_script stage of the job script` is supposed to refer to your `script` directive with `echo`, `ls`, `whoami`, etc?

Comment: Yes I believe so.